# object HTMLInputElement instead of a string only the first time I activate my function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, object, pdo

I would like to return my last insert ID from a table after adding an element.
I'm submitting the form via jquery.

Here's the main part of my code :

addEntry.php

```
[functional data insertion, blabla]
echo $connection->lastInsertId('ID');
```

jquery :

```
            $("#dishAdd").click(function(){                    

                $.post('./requests/addEntry.php',
                    {
                        position:dishPosition,
                        type:dishType
                    },
                    function(data) {
                        dishID = data;
                        alert(dishID);
                });

                $("#myelement").append(dishID);

            });
```

The problem is, when I first click on #dishAdd, my $("#myelement").append(dishID) returns :

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
```

instead of my last ID.
If I click another time, it returns the right value, same for all following clicks.

Do you know why it returns [object HTMLInputElement] on the first click?
Note that the alert(dishID); always shows the right value, even on the first click.

I hope you can help me!

edit : 
I fixed it by moving

```
$("#myelement").append(dishID);
```

into

```
function(data) { $("#myelement").append(data); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try alert(dishID * 1)
Try add 'debugger;' to your code, then open page in Chrome, press f12 before refreshing of page, select Source tab and open your page. Then check, what for value contains dishID

Comment: I managed to fix my problem by putting $("#myelement").append(dishID); in my function(data){}